# Likelihood in MAP and MLE for linear regression

Tags: probability, statistics, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

In MAP estimation for linear regression task, the posterior of the weight given the data is written as $p(w|X,Y)=\frac{p(Y|X,w)p(w)}{p(Y|X)}$, why the likelihood is not $p(X,Y|w)$?

From my understanding, according to the Bayes rule $p(B|A)=\frac{p(A|B)p(B)}{p(A)}$. I suppose $A=w$ and $B = X,Y$ in the MAP estimation and get $p(w|X,Y)=\frac{p(X,Y|w)p(w)}{p(X,Y)}$. Even after using the product rule, I could only get $p(w|X,Y)=\frac{p(Y|X,w)p(X|w)p(w)}{p(Y|X)p(X)}$, how to the terms $p(X|w)$ and $p(X)$ cancel out and get the formula above?

Comment: If $X$ is the independent variable in your regression, $Y$ the dependent variable and $w$ the parameter, then $X$ is not really a random variable and if it is then it is independent of $w$.  Your model is that $Y$ is a random variable which depends  on $X$ and $w$, and $w$ is an unknown parameter which you model with a prior distribution then updated to a posterior distribution.  In terms of your question, $X$ is what it is, and does not depend on $w$, so to the extent $p(X)$ and $p(X \mid w)$ are meaningful in any sense then they are equal.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense!